# Need help combining two SQL selections into one for pivot table

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I need help combining two table selections into one for a pivot table.

Table A columns: State, City, Device, Stat_A, Stat_B

- **Device** column has multiple listings

Table B columns: State, City, Device, Stat_C

- **Device** column only has 'All Devices' as an entry

Example input:

**A:**

```
CA, San Fran, A, 1, 2
CA, San Jose, A, 3, 5
```

**B:**

```
CA, San Fran, All Devices, 66
CA, San Jose, All Devices, 77
```

**Result:**

```
CA, San Fran, A, 1, 2, null
CA, San Jose, A, 3, 5, null
CA, San Fran, All Devices, null, null, 66
CA, San Jose, All Devices, null, null, 77
```

The idea here is when I create the pivot table and set Device as column names, I get the columns A and All Devices where I just hide some of the sub-columns like stat_a and stat_b under All Devices column. From the above example only 2 rows (excluding by state row) would show as the table would sum to city-state as those are the rows of the pivot table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `union`.

```
SELECT State, City, Device, Stat_A, Stat_B, null FROM A UNION
SELECT State, City, Device, null, null, Stat_C FROM B;
```

It would be useful to know on what DB engine you are running this query, but that should work.

Comment: The selecting from an Oracle SQL server via ODBC.

Comment: Note that the duplicate answer indicates that, using Oracle, you would need to use `AS Stat_C` after the `null` in the first part of the UNION, and similarly after the `null`s in the second part.